# Odoo v9 - onchange does not see the value of the changing field

Tags: model, odoo, odoo-9

I have added a field to product.template called uom_class .  When it changes, I need to change other fields based upon its value.  Unfortunately, Odoo is treating it like its empty, and always returns False.  I have no idea why.  Here is my code

```py
class product_uom_class(models.Model):
    _inherits = {'product.uom.categ':'catid'}
    _name = 'productuom.class'
    catid = fields.Many2one('product.uom.categ', ondelete='cascade', required=True)
    test = fields.Boolean('isbool',default=True)
    # [...]

class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    uom_class = fields.Many2one(
        'productuom.class', 'Per Product UOM Conversion Class',
        required=False, help="Unit of Measure class for Per Product UOM")


@api.onchange('uom_class')
def onchange_uom_class(self):
    print self.list_price
    print self.uom_id.name
    print self.uom_class
    print self.uom_class.test
    print self.uom_class.catid.name
```

The results from the python command line are

```
24.0
Dozen(s)
productuom.class()
False
False
```

The selection I'm changing it to is not null, and it has all of its data show up fine in List view.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem.  It was actually an issue in the views...

I had accidentally copy and pasted the  declaration for uom_class in modifications I made on another tab. So my variable was listed twice.  Odoo saw that it was being changed, but I guess it was not handling it very well having two of the exact same fields.

A very stupid mistake.  Sorry to anyone who wasted their time on this.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:
`print self.uom_class['test']`